# Running JUnit integration tests from a JSP?

Tags: junit

we need to do some integration testing of some Java classes which we want to run inside a Weblogic server. We have a JUnit test suite that runs a set of Junit test classes, and I would like to know if is a good idea to write a JSP that runs the test suite and prints out the results in a graphical way, in case we won't be able to access via SSH to the server and run the tests via console.

- Step 1: We upload the jar file with the tests and the JSP
- Step 2: We call the JSP via a browser
- Step 3: Profit! Our tests are running and we have visual feedback.

Am I right or wrong? Thanks for your advices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [Cactus](http://jakarta.apache.org/cactus/) to do this,

See the following article for reference:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/server-side-unit-tests-096611.html

That should save you having to write extra code, not sure about visual feedback but the Cactus page seems to suggest that when running in a servlet container like Tomcat you should get the results visually:

http://jakarta.apache.org/cactus/integration/howto_tomcat.html