# Run JUnit Tests through web page

Tags: java, html, testing, web-applications, junit

We would like to have a set of tests as part of our web application. The tests will be used for analyzing the health status of the application, so a support person or a scheduler can run the test to see if the application itself and various required remote systems are available.

I have seen this being done using some kind of webbased JUnit frontend, it allowed to run tests and reported the results as HTML. This would be great because the developers know JUnit, but I couldn't find the library in the intertubes.

Where can I find a library doing this?

Comment: If you're goal is seeing what's available I don't think you want tests for that, you want to add monitoring capabilities (like with JMX), so you can have some sort of dashboard that tells you what's going on.

Comment: If the developers know JUnit, then integrating it with cruisecontrol will definitely give you the reporting you're after...

Comment: Related (but not duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/q/2225974/12597

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some free services to verify the availability of your system. Here are two that I've used:

- [mon.itor.us](http://mon.itor.us/)
- [pingdom](http://www.pingdom.com/)

Another thing you can take a look at is [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/), but it does not have a web UI.

Original answer:

Perhaps you mean functional tests (that can be run through JUnit). Take a look at
[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) - it's web functional testing tool.

(Note that these are not unit tests. They don't test individual units of the code. Furthermore unit tests are executed at build time, not at runtime.)

Comment: I'm aware that these aren't unit tests. Thats why I didn't call them unit tests. AFAIK Selenium tests a web app through the GUI. If this is true, this is not what I am looking for. I want to control my tests through a webgui, not the other way round.

Comment: and what should these tests test then?

Comment: The availability of remote systems that are needed by the webapplication. I'd call them 'monitoring tests'

Answer (score 1):

Bozho is correct, these are not unit tests but I have done something similar. At my company I am not the one that ultimately deploys these things to our test environment or production environment. During development I create a couple of servlets that test things like it can get a valid database connection, it can hit our AD server etc. It than basically prints out a message and indicates success or failure.

That way when I have the code deployed to one of our environments, I can have the person deploying it hit the URL and make sure everything comes back OK. When I get ready to do the final deployment I just remove the servlet config.

Comment: That sounds pretty much like what I am trying to do. So you wrote the stuff yourself? Hmm. Was hoping there would be some open source project doing this ..

Comment: I didn't run any junit tests or create a test framework or anything, I just created a simple Servlet that I could do what I needed to do. The amount of code was really minimal.

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably looking for is [CruiseControl.Net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccnet/files/CruiseControl.NET%20Releases/) - it combines with NUnit/JUnit etc to make an automated testing framework with HTML reporting tools and a tray app for your desktop as well.  I actually just downloaded it again an hour ago for a new role - it's really good.

It can be used to run anything from unit tests to getting files from source control, to kicking off compiler builds or rebooting servers (when used with NAnt - a .Net build tool).

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a set of tests composed and ready to run, then [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) can run those tests on a schedule and report on the results.

Answer (score 0):

Update: If you're looking for a tool to check your servers and applications every few minutes for availability check out [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/).

---

Maybe you mean some kind of acceptance test tool. If so, have a look at [Fitnesse](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.OneMinuteDescription).

Answer (score 0):

You should look for a Continous Integration tool like Jenkin.